# array_values does not return null

Tags: php

The Following code:

```
$a = array('');
$a = array_values($a);
print_r($a);
```

Produces :

```
Array ( [0] => )
```

I was expecting null from the function array_values but instead it returns the array itself. Is this the intended behavior or is it the desired output?

Comment: `''` !== `null`.... `array_values()` returns ___all of the values___ from the array, as a new enumerated array

Comment: use `array_filter($a)`